# How to identify which Firefox tab is playing a short audio sample in irregular intervals?

Tags: linux, firefox

So since a few days, I irregularily get a bell-type sound from Firefox. I know it’s from Firefox because I spent an hour or so watching pavucontrol to find out which application was responsible for that sound (It was CubeAudioUtils or something similar with the Firefox logo).

I first suspected it was a monitoring application, but muting that tab does not have any effect on the sound. It still occurs irregularly.

I need to find out which tab is responsible for that *irregular*, *rare* (maybe once per half an hour, maybe more rare) and *short* (maybe a second or two) sound. Due to these properties, checking which tabs shows the speaker icon while the sound is playing is not a viable option. Closing all tabs is also not an option, not only because I need those tabs, but also because it may occur again in the future (I assume it is some kind of web application I use), and then I am no wiser about the cause.

Also not an option are addons which block audio from playing at all or forcing click-to-play everywhere.

How can I do this?

This is on Debian unstable with Firefox 45.6.0.

Comment: Are you being @pinged in a chat room maybe?

Comment: @DavidPostill Nice idea – I’m in no chat rooms though. Unless a website embeds one wtihout my knowledge, in which case I still need a way to track it down.

Comment: FWIW, I figured out that it was some monitoring application pinging about stuff, but I hadn’t used it before and had no idea it can do that. Soo… this isn’t really a solution.