# Which tab made a sound in Firefox?

Tags: linux, firefox, audio, browser-tabs

I know that there is a nice little symbol that makes it possible to see which tabs are making a sound. But is there a way to see which tab that just MADE a sound?

The reason I'm asking is that I heard some notification sound I did not recognize, and it's driving me nuts not knowing.

Comment: There's a similar question and it is unanswered unfortunately  https://superuser.com/questions/1165657/how-to-identify-which-firefox-tab-is-playing-a-short-audio-sample-in-irregular-i

Answer (score -1):

I've written a quick Firefox extension to log tab audio state changes to the browser console. It currently doesn't take into account additional variables like muted tabs, but that functionality can be added if the add-on in its current state doesn't answer the question satisfactorily.

The extension generates console entries like:

```
tab '(1) Messenger' is playing sound               background.js:10:13
tab '(1) Messenger' stopped playing sound          background.js:10:13
tab '... - YouTube' stopped playing sound          background.js:10:13
tab '(1) Messenger' is playing sound               background.js:10:13
```

so filtering the browser console contents by "tab" and displaying only entries from the [Logs] category should reduce the amount of output from other logging sources.

You can download the add-on from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RPEfZw8mW27WZTGhD7vZQBv22ioBgE8e/view?usp=sharing).

I can't guess your platform specifics or software versions, but I've verified the extension's basic functionality using Firefox 67 on Linux for both YouTube and FB Messenger.

Comment: The URL is to a drive that defaults to refuse access and require permission from you. Is it intended?